# Assigning sub type collection to parent type

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, casting

The following code does not give any error :

```
List<A> l = new LinkedList<A>();
l.add(new B()); // B extends A
```

Then why does the below give error:

```
List<B> l = new LinkedList<B>();
List<A> l1 = l;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` extends `A` does not mean `List<B>` extends `List<A>`. Assigning sub type collection to parent type will make it not type safe.

```
List<B> ListB = new LinkedList<B>();
List<A> ListA = ListB ;  // Suppose you can compile it without error
ListA.add(new C());  // You can put C into ListA if C extends A
B b = ListB.get(0); // Then when you retrieve from ListB, you get a C, not type safe!
```

You need a wildcard to guarantee type safe and make it compile:

```
List<B> ListB = new LinkedList<B>();
List<? extends A> ListSubA = ListB ;
ListSubA.add(new C()); // Compile error, a wildcard can prevent user putting C into it
ListB.add(new B());  // You can only add new element by ListB 
B b = ListB.get(0);  // Type safe
```

Comment: But by assigning the list am I not just saying I will add the sub class in the list?

Answer (score 1):

It is explained here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Basically `List<A>` is treated as a separate (not related in any way) type from `List<B>` so when you declare a reference of type `List<A>` it cannot point to an object of type `List<B>`.

There is a nice discussion here - [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)